# Dojo 1.7 datagrid change row colors based on the text in the cell

Tags: datagrid, dojo, styles, row

I would like to change the datagrid background colors of each individual cell using dojo tools, but i am trying a couple of things, but i cant find the correct solution.

The code below is used to create the data grid

```
 var myStore, dataStore, grid;
    require([
            "dojo/store/JsonRest",
            "dojo/store/Memory",
            "dojo/store/Cache",
            "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
            "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
            "dojo/query",
            "dijit/form/Button",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function (JsonRest, Memory, Cache, DataGrid, ObjectStore, query) {
            myStore = Cache(JsonRest({ target: "/Blog/Action/", idProperty: "Id" }), Memory({ idProperty: "Id" }));
            grid = new DataGrid({
                store: dataStore = ObjectStore({ objectStore: myStore }),
                //  items:dataStore.items,
                structure: [
                    { name: "Blog Id", field: "Id", width: "50px", },
                    { name: "Name", field: "Name", width: "200px",classes:"Name" },
                    { name: "Phone Number", field: "Phone Number", width: "200px",classes:"test" }
                ]
            }, "grid"); // make sure you have a target HTML element with this id

            grid.startup();

            dojo.query("body").addClass("claro");

            grid.canSort = function () { return false };
        });
```

The code below is to try to change the color based on the index of the chosen value but nothing is happening, i mean no errors but it doesn't go inside the script at all.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true">
       dojo.connect(grid, 'onStyleRow', this, function (row) {
        var item = grid.getItem(row.index);
        if (row.index == 0) {
            row.customClasses = "highlightRow";
            row.customStyles += 'background-color:#FFB93F;';
        }

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code inside your `<script>` tag, which has a 'src' is never run. See [dojo/_base Documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/connect.html) on how to pull in connect module the AMD way

This should work

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async:true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
```

And hook with grid

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    require(["dojo/_base/connect"], function(connect) {
       connect.connect(grid, 'onStyleRow', this, function (row) {
          var item = grid.getItem(row.index);
          if (row.index == 0) {
             row.customClasses = "highlightRow";
             row.customStyles += 'background-color:#FFB93F;';
          }
       });    
    });
</script>
```

If youre declaring your grid via markup, you could use this pattern:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid" data-dojo-props="???">
  <script type="dojo/method" event="onStyleRow" args="row">
        var item = grid.getItem(row.index);
        if (row.index == 0) {
            row.customClasses = "highlightRow";
            row.customStyles += 'background-color:#FFB93F;';
        } else {
             this.inherited(arguments);
        }
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried both codes above but i got an error `TypeError: dojo.connect is not a function`

Comment: NOTE the closing `</script>` tag after dojo/dojo.js load in. If still, dojo.connect is not defined, either youre having a custombase or have forgotten to pull in the connect module (is default part of kernel though)

Comment: I removed the `dojo.dojo.js` and i am using `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, isDebug: true, parseOnLoad: true">
</script>` and when i use dojo.connect alone inside a `<sciprt>` like this `<script>
dojo.connect(grid, 'onStyleRow', this, function (row) {
        var item = grid.getItem(row.index);
        if (row.index == 0) {
            row.customClasses = "highlightRow";
            row.customStyles += 'background-color:#FFB93F;';
        }

    });` I am getting the same error.

Comment: See https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/connect.html on how to pull in connect module the AMD way